# jQueryMobile dialog close button triggers click on item behind it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

In a jQuery Mobile project, have a dialog box (not a popup) with some fields and two buttons styled like so:

```
        <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="none" href="#"
            data-icon="check" data-iconpos="left" id="saveEdit">Save
        </a>
        <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="none" href="#"
            data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="left" id="closeEdit">Cancel
        </a>
```

When one of them is clicked, a click event handler closes the dialog:

```
$(document).on("vclick", "#saveEdit", function () {

    LoginCookie(EditDoc, "Y");
    $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

However, when this happens, a click event is also fired on anything that was "behind" the dialog, almost as if you are tapping "through" the dialog button, even though it still fires a click event on the button. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I believe a click event has been set to the parent of the dialog

Comment: It has not. Plus, it's not that it's triggering any click event code I have wired up on the page behind it, but it is automatically clicking a link directly behind the dialog when the dialog is closed.

Comment: place a white transparent div behind dialog width : 100%, height : 100%

Comment: Are you familiar with jQueryMobile? I don't believe that will work with a jQueryMobile dialog. I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have fixed it:

```
 $(document).on("vclick", "#saveEdit", function (e) {


            e.preventDefault();


            LoginCookie(EditDoc, "Y");
            $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding the only thing that works for me is to make the modal blocking, particularly for laggy interfaces, like just about all older Android versions. You're intending for the user to tap on elements within the modal to close it. Here's a pattern as part of your handler:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(myModal).on({
            popupbeforeposition: function () { //make the popup blocking - no click outside to close
                $('.ui-popup-screen').off();
            }
        }).popup("open");
    }, 500);
```

Of course, this means the user can't just tap outside the modal to close it. But if you have a lot of form or other interactive elements on the page, I think this is a pretty crucial adjustment for usability.